# R - Switch levels and values in a factor

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to convert a factor into a numeric data type, but noticed that my values and levels are swapped, so when I convert, I just get the count of each value instead of the value itself.

I've tried `as.numeric(as.character(data$column)`, but am met with NAs.

`str(data$column)` produces the output: "Factor w/ 394 levels "x1","x2","x3"...: y y x y...
when in reality the levels should be in the place of the values.

```
dput(head(train$Sqft, 100))

structure(c(13L, 13L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 62L, 17L, 13L, 17L, 
29L, 13L, 4L, 17L, 39L, 29L, 17L, 38L, 17L, 12L, 17L, 39L, 39L, 
96L, 39L, 39L, 82L, 30L, 29L, 216L, 96L, 25L, 169L, 195L, 195L, 
169L, 169L, 168L, 170L, 167L, 167L, 194L, 167L, 195L, 169L, 169L, 
168L, 195L, 169L, 169L, 196L, 169L, 191L, 168L, 169L, 196L, 196L, 
169L, 195L, 168L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 195L, 197L, 169L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 195L, 170L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 197L, 202L, 173L, 178L, 
271L, 265L, 271L, 271L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 265L, 271L, 166L, 33L, 
166L, 33L, 166L, 33L, 166L, 33L, 166L, 33L, 166L, 33L), .Label = c("1,072", 
"1,098", "1,168", "1,200", "1,236", "1,280", "1,288", "1,294", 
"1,301", "1,314", "1,317", "1,320", "1,360", "1,364", "1,368", 
"1,375", "1,380", "1,382", "1,394", "1,400", "1,408", "1,424", 
"1,496", "1,500", "1,507", "1,512", "1,515", "1,522", "1,554", 
"1,562", "1,566", "1,568", "1,570", "1,595", "1,596", "1,607", 
"1,613", "1,614", "1,630", "1,636", "1,638", "1,642", "1,654", 
"1,664", "1,668", "1,680", "1,694", "1,706", "1,712", "1,718", 
"1,719", "1,720", "1,722", "1,724", "1,726", "1,731", "1,732", 
"1,739", "1,744", "1,748", "1,761", "1,770", "1,800", "1,802", 
"1,809", "1,812", "1,816", "1,824", "1,831", "1,832", "1,843", 
"1,862", "1,866", "1,882", "1,888", "1,890", "1,894", "1,898", 
"1,920", "1,924", "1,930", "1,940", "1,948", "1,953", "1,960", 
"1,968", "1,970", "1,972", "1,978", "1,981", "1,987", "1,995", 
"1,996", "2,004", "2,014", "2,019", "2,042", "2,047", "2,060", 
"2,085", "2,088", "2,089", "2,098", "2,102", "2,116", "2,130", 
"2,131", "2,132", "2,134", "2,135", "2,151", "2,153", "2,155", 
"2,168", "2,181", "2,184", "2,185", "2,188", "2,196", "2,198", 
"2,203", "2,206", "2,225", "2,232", "2,239", "2,249", "2,260", 
"2,270", "2,278", "2,286", "2,290", "2,295", "2,305", "2,308", 
"2,312", "2,313", "2,321", "2,326", "2,335", "2,336", "2,338", 
"2,348", "2,352", "2,360", "2,373", "2,374", "2,384", "2,385", 
"2,394", "2,396", "2,400", "2,408", "2,410", "2,436", "2,437", 
"2,442", "2,452", "2,464", "2,478", "2,483", "2,489", "2,496", 
"2,497", "2,501", "2,503", "2,509", "2,510", "2,512", "2,514", 
"2,518", "2,519", "2,527", "2,530", "2,536", "2,556", "2,558", 
"2,559", "2,562", "2,582", "2,592", "2,600", "2,604", "2,616", 
"2,622", "2,632", "2,635", "2,638", "2,674", "2,682", "2,692", 
"2,710", "2,714", "2,727", "2,730", "2,732", "2,734", "2,738", 
"2,760", "2,763", "2,772", "2,776", "2,782", "2,786", "2,787", 
"2,788", "2,792", "2,798", "2,804", "2,808", "2,813", "2,820", 
"2,824", "2,826", "2,836", "2,838", "2,839", "2,841", "2,856", 
"2,860", "2,864", "2,874", "2,885", "2,898", "2,902", "2,903", 
"2,904", "2,906", "2,932", "2,934", "2,938", "2,940", "2,943", 
"2,948", "2,958", "2,959", "2,964", "2,968", "2,982", "2,983", 
"2,988", "2,989", "2,992", "2,996", "3,000", "3,004", "3,010", 
"3,011", "3,012", "3,014", "3,026", "3,032", "3,040", "3,042", 
"3,043", "3,044", "3,050", "3,056", "3,060", "3,064", "3,067", 
"3,068", "3,078", "3,082", "3,086", "3,090", "3,108", "3,112", 
"3,114", "3,116", "3,124", "3,126", "3,139", "3,147", "3,154", 
"3,156", "3,160", "3,161", "3,172", "3,176", "3,178", "3,180", 
"3,184", "3,190", "3,196", "3,204", "3,210", "3,214", "3,234", 
"3,238", "3,239", "3,253", "3,262", "3,269", "3,272", "3,277", 
"3,292", "3,295", "3,302", "3,326", "3,341", "3,342", "3,370", 
"3,373", "3,374", "3,404", "3,413", "3,420", "3,422", "3,425", 
"3,430", "3,442", "3,443", "3,459", "3,460", "3,462", "3,470", 
"3,520", "3,529", "3,536", "3,545", "3,550", "3,551", "3,566", 
"3,576", "3,578", "3,594", "3,614", "3,628", "3,630", "3,632", 
"3,634", "3,648", "3,663", "3,666", "3,676", "3,678", "3,680", 
"3,700", "3,727", "3,738", "3,740", "3,746", "3,765", "3,767", 
"3,804", "3,808", "3,837", "3,840", "3,872", "3,889", "3,913", 
"3,924", "3,956", "3,991", "4,056", "4,086", "4,116", "4,135", 
"4,145", "4,152", "4,155", "4,158", "4,169", "4,231", "4,256", 
"4,305", "4,334", "4,358", "4,361", "4,376", "4,432", "4,448", 
"4,464", "4,481", "4,500", "4,529", "4,554", "4,568", "4,712", 
"4,760", "4,767", "4,802", "4,845", "4,892", "4,928", "5,070", 
"5,328", "5,354", "5,386", "5,456", "5,524", "5,536", "5,701", 
"6,486"), class = "factor")
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the data that we can work with. Use `dput(head(data$column, 100))`, which will output that data into the console so you can copy and paste it into your question. The output of `dput()` allows us to recreate the data structure and work with it to figure out the issue.

Comment: Please post a little bit of what your factor looks like, `dput(drolevels(data$column[1:10]))` would help a lot. I'm not sure what you mean by "the levels should be in the place of the values". The levels should be the unique values. Generally `as.numeric(as.character())` works well when your factor levels are numbers, e.g., `"2020", "2021"` to convert to `2020, 2021`. Here, it looks like you factor levels are `"x1", "x2"` which cannot be converted directly to numeric.... please also show your desired output.

Comment: @BenNorris with "394 levels" a `droplevels()` in the `dput` will help a lot.

Comment: If you just want the level numbers - i.e., your first level becomes 1, your second 2, etc., then use `as.numeric()` directly, without the `as.character()`. Or, if you want to extract the numbers from the values, `x1` becomes 1, `y32` becomes 32, then use some light regex, something like `as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(data$column, "[0-9]+"))`

Comment: Just added the output, let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
# base r solution 
type.convert(gsub(",", "", levels(train$Sqft))) # remove a comma i.e. ',' which was used as grouping mark and then convert to integer. 

# tidyverse way
readr::parse_number(levels(train$Sqft))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
as.numeric(as.character(sub(',', '.', x)))

#   [1] 1.360 1.360 1.380 1.360 1.360 1.320 1.770 1.380 1.360 1.380 1.554
#  [12] 1.360 1.200 1.380 1.630 1.554 1.380 1.614 1.380 1.320 1.380 1.630
#  [23] 1.630 2.019 1.630 1.630 1.940 1.562 1.554 2.839 2.019 1.507 2.514
#  [34] 2.732 2.732 2.514 2.514 2.512 2.518 2.510 2.510 2.730 2.510 2.732
#  [45] 2.514 2.514 2.512 2.732 2.514 2.514 2.734 2.514 2.710 2.512 2.514
#  [56] 2.734 2.734 2.514 2.732 2.512 2.514 2.514 2.514 2.732 2.738 2.514
#  [67] 2.514 2.514 2.514 2.732 2.518 2.530 2.530 2.530 2.530 2.738 2.782
#  [78] 2.530 2.562 3.126 3.090 3.126 3.126 3.090 3.090 3.090 3.090 3.126
#  [89] 2.509 1.570 2.509 1.570 2.509 1.570 2.509 1.570 2.509 1.570 2.509
# [100] 1.570
```

Or more efficiently:

```
as.numeric(sub(',', '.', levels(x), fixed = TRUE))[x]
```